# Using Text::CSV on a String Containing Quotes

Tags: csv, perl

I have pored over this site (and others) trying to glean the answer for this but have been unsuccessful.

```
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 } );

$line = q(data="a=1,b=2",c=3);

my $csvParse  = $csv->parse($line);

my @fields = $csv->fields();

for my $field (@fields) {
    print "FIELD ==> $field\n";
}
```

Here's the output:

```
# CSV_XS ERROR: 2034 - EIF - Loose unescaped quote @ rec 0 pos 6 field 1
FIELD ==>
```

I am expecting 2 array elements:

```
data="a=1,b=2"
c=3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get away with using [`Text::ParseWords`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords). Since you are not using real csv, it may be fine. Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $line = q(data="a=1,b=2",c=3);
my @fields = quotewords(',', 1, $line);
print Dumper \@fields;
```

This will print

```
$VAR1 = [
          'data="a=1,b=2"',
          'c=3'
        ];
```

As you requested. You may want to test further on your data.

Comment: Wow!  This does exactly what I need!

Comment: @RG925 You're welcome. If you want, you can click to accept this answer with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Your input data isn't "standard" CSV, at least not the kind that Text::CSV expects and not the kind that things like Excel produce. An *entire* field has to be quoted or not at all. The "standard" encoding of that would be `"data=""a=1,b=2""",c=3` (which you can see by asking `Text::CSV` to print your expected data using `say`).

If you pass the `allow_loose_quotes` option to the Text::CSV constructor, it won't error on your input, but it won't consider the quotes to be "protecting" the comma, so you will get three fields, namely `data="a=1`, `b=2"` and `c=3`.

Comment: Makes sense but I need to parse as described.  Other suggestions?

Comment: @RG925 does this format have a way to escape a literal double quote (inside double quotes or otherwise)?

Comment: There is a standard, [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), and the input does indeed violate the standard: "*If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then double quotes may not appear inside the fields.*"

Comment: @RG925, Re "*I need to parse as described*", If you invent your own format, you need to write your own parser